# Need to recover expired license on vmware API

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I need to retrieve the value of the expiration field of a license on the vmware API, for this I use the python pyVmomi [SDK](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi)  but I cannot find this information, to extract other information from the licenses I rely on the **licenseManager **and **licenseAssignmentManager **class, I have attached a capture with the expiration value that I wish to retrieve, I just specify that I am not expecting a Datetime type on return but a string as we can see in the capture (Expiration => Never)

[image]

I used QueryAssignedLicenses() method to retrieving licences informations, name, key, cost_unit and other

```
 content = self.smart_connect.RetrieveContent()
 lm: vim.LicenseAssignmentManager = (content.licenseManager.licenseAssignmentManager)
 query_licenses = lm.QueryAssignedLicenses(entityId=entity_id)

 for properties in query_licenses:

                name = properties.assignedLicense.name
                key = properties.assignedLicense.licenseKey
                cost_unit = properties.assignedLicense.costUnit
```

this method it's good but for the value of expiration date that's not what I'm looking for

Thanks for your help :)